# Putting several values into one column but different rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have three variables: $Title, $Pubdate and $Link

and in those variables, there are several values like this:

```
$Title = aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff
$Pubdate = aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff
$Link = aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff
```

Like this.
Then I have a table with the columns (Title, Pubdate and Link).
What I have tried:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) VALUES ('$Title', '$Pubdate', '$Link')";
mysql_query($sql,$db_con);
```

Although no error pops up, it does not perform what I want it to do.
It puts all of the values(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff) into one column(Title) and one row(ID = 1), meaning that all of the values are squished into one box, and that is not what I want :(

I want to put it into one column, but in different rows (1,2,3,4,5,6).

I've searched the web for the answer, but everything seems to be answering if they want all the values in one box which is the opposite to what I want.

Perhaps one by one, therefore `INSERT INTO ytable (Title)VALUES($Title);`, and it puts all of the values in different rows in the one column.

Comment: Explode it and then try a loop.

Comment: Is `$Title`, `$Pubdate` and `$Link` have always same number of values?

Comment: @Hassan No it does not

Comment: @raveenanigam Can you write a code and explain it to me?

Comment: $Title_value = explode(",", $Title);

Comment: Use this here you are exploding the sting with the ","
And do the same to the other two variables.

Comment: You can review my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to split your strings up into an array, so that you can 'loop' through them.

```
$Title   = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Pubdate = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Link    = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";

$TitleArray   = explode(', ',$Title);
$PubdateArray = explode(', ',$Pubdate);
$LinkArray    = explode(', ',$Link);

//Either: loop through the array and build individual INSERTS
for($i=0;$i<count($TitleArray);$i++){

    // generate an INSERT for each row
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) 
            VALUES ('$TitleArray[$i]', '$PubdateArray[$i]', '$LinkArray[$i]')";

}

//Or you could build a single query string inside the loop, and run it at the end.
```

Comment: What should I do if there is a comma within a single value?

Comment: You would need to use quotes as delimiters around each value when you are building the string.  ie: `$Title   = " 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'g,g', etc.. ";`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to generate the query to do so -

```
$Title = explode(', ', $Title);
$Pubdate = explode(', ', $Pubdate);
$Link = explode(', ', $Link);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) VALUES ";
$values= array();
foreach($Title as $key => $val) {
   $values[] = "('" . $val . "','" . (isset($Pubdate[$key]) ? $Pubdate[$key] : '')  . "','" . (isset($link[$key]) ? $link[$key] : '') . "')";
}
$sql .= implode(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `explode`, `implode` and `foreach` loop for it.

```
$Title   = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Pubdate = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Link    = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";

$Title = explode(', ', $Title);
$Pubdate = explode(', ', $Pubdate);
$Link = explode(', ', $Link);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) VALUES ";
$values= array();
foreach($Title as $key => $val)
{
   $values[] = "('" . $val . "','" . $Pubdate[$key] . "','" . $link[$key] . "')";
}
$sql .= implode(',', $values);
```

**Warning**: 
MYSQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this,

```
$Title = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Pubdate = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Link = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$titleArr = explode(",",$Title);
$pubdateeArr = explode(",",$Pubdate);
$linkArr = explode(",",$Link);

foreach($titleArr as $key => $title){
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) VALUES ('$title', '$pubdateeArr[$key]', '$linkArr[$key]')";
}
```

or you can iterate only values

```
$a = array();
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) VALUES ";

foreach($titleArr as $key => $title){
    $a[] = "('$title', '$pubdateeArr[$key]', '$linkArr[$key]')";
}
$insertSQL .= implode(",",$a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
$Title = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Pubdate = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$Link = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff";
$titleArr = explode(",",$Title);
$pubdateeArr = explode(",",$Pubdate);
$linkArr = explode(",",$Link);

foreach($titleArr as $key => $title){
if(!empty($title) && !empty($pubdateeArr[$key]) && !empty($linkArr[$key]))
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO ytable (Title, Pubdate, Link) VALUES ('$title', '$pubdateeArr[$key]', '$linkArr[$key]')";
}
```

I have tried if not empty because variables cannot have same number of values.